# Android custom file attribute for API level < 26

Tags: android

What is the best way to set/get a custom file attribute for any type of file in Android below API level 26?

From API level 26 below method can be used from java.nio.file.Files class

```
Path setAttribute (Path path, String attribute, Object value, LinkOption... options)

static Object getAttribute(Path path, String attribute, LinkOption... options)
```

Is there any alternative to do same for API level < 26?

Comment: No, the entire NIO system is unavailable before 26.  But depending on what builtin attribute you want to set there may be alternatives.  I'm not even sure if you can do custom in 26, does the default Android filesystem allow it?  Is there even a default across all devices-  I remember back in the 4.x days OEMs used a mix of different filesystems.  Please note that answer may differ for internal storage and removable storage.

Comment: Thank @GabeSechan for detailed explanation. As you mentioned, there are alternatives to set builtin attributes, if you have any info on how to do this and what all available builtin attributes are, it will really help.

I could find one way is by using native libraries. Is there any other way?